# How does trafigura hedges the price risk?

Tags: futures, hedging, commodities

I wanted to know how does company like trafigura hedges against price risk?

Example if trafigura agrees to sell say a barrell of WTI crude oil @ $56 3 months hence. How would they hedge it?

Would they buy futures for the same today and sell it after 3 months when they deliver the physical commodity as well?

I cannot understand the cash flow for different scenarios like contango or backwardation.

Comment: Lead sentence from an article earlier this year: "One of the world’s biggest traders, Trafigura, booked a $254 million (£195 million) loss from oil and gas market hedges last year."  In answer to your question, I'd say that they're not doing a very good job of hedging.

Comment: @BobBaerker so how are they sustaining the operations with such huge losses? Are the losses offset by gains in physical trade?

Comment: @BobBaerker I want to know how should they do it theoretically so that I can answer in job interview.

Comment: In order to  sustain the operations with such huge losses, they have to have sufficient assets to satisfy the minimum margin maintenance requirement (whatever that is wherever they are located).  As for hedging, I could help with the equity side but not futures.  Do some Googling and read about the various ways of hedging futures.

Comment: @BobBaerker Hedges aren't _supposed_ to make money. They're supposed to eliminate risk. Losing money in hedges simply means that their hedges lost money and offset gains in normal operations.

Comment: @D Stanley - Most hedges do not eliminate risk.  Most reduce risk (not all).  Various option strategies provide various amounts of risk reduction: covered calls, vertical spreads, collars, long puts.  Non option strategies can involve buying a stock and shorting the index it's in.  Or a simple pairs trade.  Even diversification is considered as a way to hedge.  With these last 3 strategies, it can lead to even worse results than having done no 'hedging' at all.

Comment: @D Stanley - cont. Trafigura used correlated assets to hedge (natural gas and Brent crude) and they were dead wrong on the correlation and lost big.  Per Reuters, they lost $254 million last year.  That's waaay more than just losing the cost of the hedge.

Answer (score 2):

With contango, a long-term futures contract will decline to the spot price as the time winds down. So an advantageous position would be to hold the sell-side of a long-term futures contract while also holding the physical commodity. And here storage of the physical commodity is the effective business practice.

With backwardation, a long-term futures contract will rise to the spot price as the time winds down. So a advantageous position would be to hold the buy-side of a long-term futures contract while not holding the physical commodity but sourcing the physical commodity as needed. And here the ability to quickly source and ship the physical commodity is the effective business practice. Note that the physical commodity is owed to forward sales.

Since the company mentioned has hedging losses, it was probably logistically necessary to hold large amounts of physical commodity and then necessary to hedge with sell-side futures. The sell-side futures would be expected to be short-term futures rolled over at each expiration because the oil market is in backwardation.

Look at the subject another way and when the market is in backwardation then there is no positive premium for forward sales of the physical commodity. But since something sold forward is stored but held as a short position then go-back to paragraph two.

Answer (score 0):

> if trafigura agrees to sell say a barrel of WTI crude oil @ $56 3 months hence. How would they hedge it?

There is no need to hedge in this case. I assume they they are guaranteed to own the *oil* in this scenario, and they already have a future price locked in, so there's no risk to hedge.

Now, on the other hand, if they were going to sell oil in three months are *market* prices, *then* they would have price risk.  To offset that risk, they could buy futures that expire in three month and then sell them on the day of expiry (to avoid physical delivery).

Oil producers are less inclined to hedge in a contango market, because there is a reasonable expectation for the future price to increase. However, that depends on the *reason* for the backwardation. If there is backwardation because of a short-term supply shortage, then the future price may be reasonable and hedging might be prudent.

But again, hedging is not about trying to profit on future misprices - it is about *eliminating risk*.